# I'm using NextJS and MongoDB for this basic CRUD with pagination and search. It doesn't seem to work as intended

Tags: mongodb, next.js

So my problem is that it doesn't change the page even though I click on the pages, same goes with my search bar it doesn't perform any search. I think the currentPage and searchTerm variable on the TopicsList.jsx is not passing the value to page and search variable on route.js.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TqKxw.png)

Here is the route.js:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import connectMongoDB from "../../../libs/mongodb";
import Topic from "../../../models/topic";

export async function GET(request) {
    try {
        await connectMongoDB();

        // Move the initialization here
        console.log('Received query:', request.query);

        const { page = 1, search = '' } = request.query ?? {};

        const parsedPage = parseInt(page);

        if (isNaN(parsedPage) || parsedPage < 1) {
            throw new Error('Invalid page number');
        }

        console.log('Received page:', parsedPage);
        console.log('Received search:', search);

        const regex = new RegExp(search, 'i');
        const itemsPerPage = 5;

        const totalCount = await Topic.countDocuments({
            $or: [{ title: regex }, { description: regex }],
        });
        const totalPages = Math.ceil(totalCount / itemsPerPage);

        const topics = await Topic.find({
            $or: [{ title: regex }, { description: regex }],
        })
            .skip((parsedPage - 1) * itemsPerPage)
            .limit(itemsPerPage);

        console.log('Fetched topics:', topics);

        return NextResponse.json({ topics, totalPages });
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching topics:', error);
        return NextResponse.json(
            { error: error.message || 'Internal Server Error' },
            { status: 500 }
        );
    }
}

export async function POST(request) {
    const { title, description } = await request.json();
    await connectMongoDB();
    await Topic.create({ title, description });
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Topic Created" }, { status: 201 });
}



export async function DELETE(request) {
    const id = request.nextUrl.searchParams.get("id");
    await connectMongoDB();
    await Topic.findByIdAndDelete(id);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: "Topic Deleted" }, { status: 200 });
}
```

here is the TopicsList.jsx:

```
// TopicsList.jsx
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import RemoveBtn from './RemoveBtn';
import { HiPencilAlt } from 'react-icons/hi';
import SearchBar from './SearchBar';
import Pagination from './Pagination';

const ITEMS_PER_PAGE = 5;

export default function TopicsList() {
  const [topics, setTopics] = useState([]);
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [totalPages, setTotalPages] = useState(1);
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState('');

  const fetchTopics = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/api/topics?page=${currentPage}&search=${searchTerm}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        cache: 'no-store',
      });
    
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Failed to fetch topics. Status: ${res.status}`);
      }
    
      const { topics, totalPages, fdprocessedid } = await res.json();
      setTopics(topics);
      setTotalPages(totalPages);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error loading topics:', error.message);
    }
    
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTopics();
  }, [currentPage, searchTerm]);

  const handlePageChange = (newPage) => {
    setCurrentPage(newPage);
    console.log('New page:', newPage);
    fetchTopics(); // Fetch topics when page changes
  };

  const handleSearch = (newSearchTerm) => {
    setCurrentPage(1);
    setSearchTerm(newSearchTerm);
    console.log('Search term changed to', newSearchTerm);
    fetchTopics(); // Fetch topics when search term changes
  };

  return (
    <>
      <SearchBar searchTerm={searchTerm} onSearch={handleSearch} />

      {topics.map((t) => (
        <div
          key={t._id}
          className="p-4 border-slate-300 my-3 flex justify-between gap-5 items-start"
        >
          <div>
            <h2 className="font-bold text-2xl">{t.title}</h2>
            <div>{t.description}</div>
          </div>

          <div className="flex gap-2">
            <RemoveBtn id={t._id} />
            <Link href={`/editTopic/${t._id}`}>
              <HiPencilAlt size={24} />
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}

      {totalPages > 1 && (
        <Pagination
          currentPage={currentPage}
          totalPages={totalPages}
          onPageChange={handlePageChange}
        />
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

Note: when i change the page and search value on the route,js GET function it changes

```
        const { page = 2, search = 'Game' } = request.query ?? {};
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkeqW.png)

I've tried asking ChatGPT but it seems we kept going on circles and never really solve the problem.
Was expecting when I click the page number on the website it changes to the topics inside that page number and when i search it shows me the searched item.